# Formula Of TextBox Within Chart - How Do I Refer To It Without Selecting?

Tags: vba, excel, charts, textbox, excel-formula

I have the following code that works

```
Sub TestMe()
Dim crt As ChartObject
Dim shp_Shape As Shape
Dim chartX As Chart

For Each crt In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects

    Set chartX = crt.Chart
    For Each shp_Shape In chartX.Shapes
        If shp_Shape.Type = msoTextBox Then
            shp_Shape.Select
            MsgBox (Selection.Formula)
        End If

    Next
Next

End Sub
```

What I want to do though is simplify the code so I don't have to select the shp_Shape object.
Something like  msgbox(shp_Shape.Formula)

I want to be able to read this formula without actually having to select anything.
That way I can get the property even if the sheet is hidden or  the chart/sheet is protected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The `msoTextBox` Shape doesn't have a `.Formula` property. What you need is `TextFrame2.TextRange.Text`

Try this

```
Sub TestMe()
    Dim crt As ChartObject
    Dim shp_Shape As Shape
    Dim chartX As Chart

    For Each crt In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        Set chartX = crt.Chart
        For Each shp_Shape In chartX.Shapes
            If shp_Shape.Type = msoTextBox Then
                MsgBox shp_Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

FOLLOWUP FROM COMMENTS

If your `msoTextBox` Shape is linked with a formula then you need the below

```
shp_Shape.DrawingObject.Formula
```

Comment: Hi Sid, thanks for responding. Actually you are not correct.
The is a nifty way to link text boxes to cells by typing a formula link into the formula bar while the text box is selected.
This allows a text box say within a chart to be live linked to cells. Its this formula I am trying to manipulate.

Comment: Ok. Could you explain what do yo umean?

Comment: Sure, just trying to work out how I add a screen shot for you.

Comment: Just read your edit in the first comment. See my updated post :)

Comment: So I stand corrected. The Shape doesn't have a `.Formula` Property. The `.DrawingObject` has the `.Formula` property :)

Comment: Legendary - you are a river to the people. Thanks Sid.
Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)